# Java and crossdomain.xml

Tags: java, applet, crossdomain.xml

Does anyone have any experience with Java pulling data from another domain? Assuming my client has a minimum of 1.6.0_10, how likely is it for it to work. I've seen some posts saying it works, then others saying it doesn't, and still others saying it's broken in the later micro-updates. Any insight would be appreciated.

Thanks,

-Dan

Comment: Can you give a bit more context? Are you talking about Java applets running in someone's browser?

Comment: Yes, I have a Java Applet in a browser and plan on downloading the user's Facebook images into the applet. Facebook's API (http://api.facebook.com/crossdomain.xml) to grab the URLs to the images does have a crossdomain.xml that should allow this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `crossdomain.xml` in 6u10 has restricted functionality. It requires a policy allowing any code from any site to connect. See the documentation for more details.

There has been at least one case where an **early access** release has broken `crossdomain.xml`, but fixed before update was completed.

Comment: Is this the documentation URL you were talking about? http://java.sun.com/javase/6/webnotes/6u10/plugin2/index.html#CROSSDOMAINXML

Comment: After reading the article it appears the crossdomain.xml file must exactly match:

    <cross-domain-policy>
        <allow-access-from domain="*" />
    </cross-domain-policy>


If it doesn't, then my applet won't be able to download whatever I need. As an example, the Facebook crossdomain.xml file contains: 

<cross-domain-policy>
<allow-access-from domain="*"/>
<site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="master-only"/>
</cross-domain-policy>

Which, if I understand correctly, means I will be unable to access their data from my applet.